# Solidity - TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain

I am creating a Smart Contract (BEP20 token) based on the BEP20Token template (https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc-genesis-contract/blob/master/contracts/bep20_template/BEP20Token.template).
The public contructor was modified to add some token details. However all of the standard functions are giving compile time issues like Overriding function is missing.

** here is the source code **

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

interface IBEP20 {
  /**
   * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
   */
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token decimals.
   */
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token symbol.
   */
  function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

  /**
  * @dev Returns the token name.
  */
  function name() external view returns (string memory);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the bep token owner.
   */
  function getOwner() external view returns (address);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
   */
  function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
   *
   * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event.
   */
  function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  /**
   * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
   * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
   * zero by default.
   *
   * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

  /**
   * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
   *
   * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
   *
   * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
   * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
   * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
   * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
   * desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   *
   * Emits an {Approval} event.
   */
  function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  /**
   * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
   * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
   * allowance.
   *
   * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event.
   */
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

  /**
   * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
   * another (`to`).
   *
   * Note that `value` may be zero.
   */
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

  /**
   * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
   * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
   */
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

/*
 * @dev Provides information about the current execution context, including the
 * sender of the transaction and its data. While these are generally available
 * via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct
 * manner, since when dealing with GSN meta-transactions the account sending and
 * paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application
 * is concerned).
 *
 * This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.
 */
contract Context {
  // Empty internal constructor, to prevent people from mistakenly deploying
  // an instance of this contract, which should be used via inheritance.
  constructor () internal { }

  function _msgSender() internal view returns (address payable) {
    return msg.sender;
  }

  function _msgData() internal view returns (bytes memory) {
    this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
    return msg.data;
  }
}

/**
 * @dev Wrappers over Solidity's arithmetic operations with added overflow
 * checks.
 *
 * Arithmetic operations in Solidity wrap on overflow. This can easily result
 * in bugs, because programmers usually assume that an overflow raises an
 * error, which is the standard behavior in high level programming languages.
 * `SafeMath` restores this intuition by reverting the transaction when an
 * operation overflows.
 *
 * Using this library instead of the unchecked operations eliminates an entire
 * class of bugs, so it's recommended to use it always.
 */
library SafeMath {
  /**
   * @dev Returns the addition of two unsigned integers, reverting on
   * overflow.
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `+` operator.
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - Addition cannot overflow.
   */
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

    return c;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting on
   * overflow (when the result is negative).
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
   */
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting with custom message on
   * overflow (when the result is negative).
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
   */
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b <= a, errorMessage);
    uint256 c = a - b;

    return c;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, reverting on
   * overflow.
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `*` operator.
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - Multiplication cannot overflow.
   */
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
    // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
    // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    uint256 c = a * b;
    require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

    return c;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts on
   * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
   * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
   * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - The divisor cannot be zero.
   */
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts with custom message on
   * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
   * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
   * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - The divisor cannot be zero.
   */
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
    require(b > 0, errorMessage);
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

    return c;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
   * Reverts when dividing by zero.
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
   * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
   * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - The divisor cannot be zero.
   */
  function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
   * Reverts with custom message when dividing by zero.
   *
   * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
   * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
   * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - The divisor cannot be zero.
   */
  function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b != 0, errorMessage);
    return a % b;
  }
}

/**
 * @dev Contract module which provides a basic access control mechanism, where
 * there is an account (an owner) that can be granted exclusive access to
 * specific functions.
 *
 * By default, the owner account will be the one that deploys the contract. This
 * can later be changed with {transferOwnership}.
 *
 * This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the modifier
 * `onlyOwner`, which can be applied to your functions to restrict their use to
 * the owner.
 */
contract Ownable is Context {
  address private _owner;

  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

  /**
   * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
   */
  constructor () internal {
    address msgSender = _msgSender();
    _owner = msgSender;
    emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
   */
  function owner() public view returns (address) {
    return _owner;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
   * `onlyOwner` functions anymore. Can only be called by the current owner.
   *
   * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
   * thereby removing any functionality that is only available to the owner.
   */
  function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
    _owner = address(0);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
   * Can only be called by the current owner.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    _transferOwnership(newOwner);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
   */
  function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal {
    require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
    _owner = newOwner;
  }
}

contract BEP20Token  is Context, IBEP20, Ownable {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

  uint256 private _totalSupply;
  uint8 private _decimals;
  string private _symbol;
  string private _name;

  constructor() public {
    _name = "Money Paiger Coin";
    _symbol = "MPTT";
    _decimals = 18;
    _totalSupply = 10000000 * 10 ** 18;   //10 million Total Supply
    _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;

    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the bep token owner.
   */
  function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
    return owner();
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token decimals.
   */
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8) {
    return _decimals;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Returns the token symbol.
   */
  function symbol() external view returns (string memory) {
    return _symbol;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Returns the token name.
  */
  function name() external view returns (string memory) {
    return _name;
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {BEP20-totalSupply}.
   */
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {BEP20-balanceOf}.
   */
  function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
    return _balances[account];
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {BEP20-transfer}.
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
   * - the caller must have a balance of at least `amount`.
   */
  function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {BEP20-allowance}.
   */
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256) {
    return _allowances[owner][spender];
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {BEP20-approve}.
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
   */
  function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {BEP20-transferFrom}.
   *
   * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance. This is not
   * required by the EIP. See the note at the beginning of {BEP20};
   *
   * Requirements:
   * - `sender` and `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
   * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
   * - the caller must have allowance for `sender`'s tokens of at least
   * `amount`.
   */
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Atomically increases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
   *
   * This is an alternative to {approve} that can be used as a mitigation for
   * problems described in {BEP20-approve}.
   *
   * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance.
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
   */
  function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Atomically decreases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
   *
   * This is an alternative to {approve} that can be used as a mitigation for
   * problems described in {BEP20-approve}.
   *
   * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance.
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
   * - `spender` must have allowance for the caller of at least
   * `subtractedValue`.
   */
  function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "BEP20: decreased allowance below zero"));
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `msg.sender`, increasing
   * the total supply.
   *
   * Requirements
   *
   * - `msg.sender` must be the token owner
   */
  function mint(uint256 amount) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    _mint(_msgSender(), amount);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Moves tokens `amount` from `sender` to `recipient`.
   *
   * This is internal function is equivalent to {transfer}, and can be used to
   * e.g. implement automatic token fees, slashing mechanisms, etc.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event.
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - `sender` cannot be the zero address.
   * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
   * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
   */
  function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(sender != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");

    _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
  }

  /** @dev Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing
   * the total supply.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event with `from` set to the zero address.
   *
   * Requirements
   *
   * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
   */
  function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(account != address(0), "BEP20: mint to the zero address");

    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the
   * total supply.
   *
   * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
   *
   * Requirements
   *
   * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
   * - `account` must have at least `amount` tokens.
   */
  function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(account != address(0), "BEP20: burn from the zero address");

    _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount, "BEP20: burn amount exceeds balance");
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
    emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the `owner`s tokens.
   *
   * This is internal function is equivalent to `approve`, and can be used to
   * e.g. set automatic allowances for certain subsystems, etc.
   *
   * Emits an {Approval} event.
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - `owner` cannot be the zero address.
   * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
   */
  function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

    _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
    emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`.`amount` is then deducted
   * from the caller's allowance.
   *
   * See {_burn} and {_approve}.
   */
  function _burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    _burn(account, amount);
    _approve(account, _msgSender(), _allowances[account][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: burn amount exceeds allowance"));
  }
}
```

Couple of issues

1. Constructor public () - Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
2. function getOwner() - TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier. --> MoneyPaigerToken.sol:365:3: | 365 | function getOwner

Not sure what is missing here.

Regards
Sam

Comment: Mismatch between the source code and Solidity compiler version.

Comment: so you mean the Template was written for an old version of the Compiler and the new compiler version does not recognize some of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Constructor public () - Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.*

The warning message says it all. You can safely remove the `public` visibility modifier because it's ignored anyway.

If you marked the `BEP20Token` contract abstract, you would need to have a child contract inheriting from it, could not deploy the `BEP20Token` itself, but would have to deploy the child contract. Which is not what you want in this case.

```
constructor() {  // remove the `public` modifier
```

---

> *function getOwner() - TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier. --> MoneyPaigerToken.sol:365:3: | 365 | function getOwner*

Using interfaces in Solidity is not the same as in most other languages. Using expressions from other languages, there's no keyword for `implements` (an interface). There's just `extends` (a parent class) - in Solidity called simply `is` (a child of a class).

Interfaces are mostly used when you're interacting with other contracts (deployed on a different address). Example:

```
function getOtherTokenDecimals(address tokenAddress) external returns (uint8) {
    IBEP20 tokenInstance = IBEP20(tokenAddress);
    return tokenInstance.decimals();
}
```

As I wrote earlier, there's currently no expression for a contract implementing an interface. Just for extending a class. So your `BEP20Token is IBEP20` extends the (interface) class and because the function `getOwner()` is already defined in the parent, you need to explicitly state that you want to override by using the `override` modifier.

```
function getOwner() external override view returns (address) {  // add the `override` modifier
```

However, my approach instead of explicitly overriding the functions would be to move the events definitions to your `BEP20Token`, remove the interface definition and its inheritance because it's not used anywhere else in the code.

```
contract BEP20Token is Context, Ownable {  // remove the `IBEP20` inheritance

    // move the event definitions here
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
```

---

You can also remove the `Context` from the list of `BEP20Token` parents, because `Ownable` is also inheriting from `Context`.

```
contract BEP20Token is Ownable {  // remove the `Context` parent
```

Comment: Thank you Petr..So much of learning..I got your points..So removed all the Interface Definitions..Didnt overirde the functions..Contract looks good now, only some SPDX license identifier warning..Let me post the cleaned up code

Comment: Let me put the code in a new thread and post the link here...Thanks so much Petr

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the error, you have to explicitly override the function in the child contract using the 'override' modifier.

```html
  function getOwner() override external view returns (address);
```

And subsequently make the function you want to override in the parent contract virtual by adding 'virtual' modifier.