# Solidity overriding function is missing "override" specifier

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm using some templated code to create a token. Unfortunately I am running into the following error.

Screenshot attached, with code below. Using remix.ethereum. Identical error on each function. What's causing this and how do I fix it?

[image]

EDIT - I've added code showing the interface, constructor, etc. This is all the code now.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint256 balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint256 remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokens) external returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint256 tokens);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe Math Library
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a); c = a - b; 
        
    } 
    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { 
        c = a * b; require(a == 0 || c / a == b); 
        
    } 
    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { 
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}


contract TTKN is IERC20, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it

    uint256 public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowed;

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor() {
        name = "Test Token";
        symbol = "TTKN";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;

        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
}

function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[tokenOwner];
}

function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
}

function approve(address spender, uint256 tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
    return true;
}

function transfer(address to, uint256 tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
    allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solidity - TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485324/solidity-typeerror-overriding-function-is-missing-override-specifier)

Comment: I think so, I basically added `override` to all the above function definitions, so now they look like `function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) `. I'm not sure exactly why this is needed, so I hope it works fine.

Comment: I think your contract in which you see errors have been thrown is inherited from another contract. Also in the first contract there are some functions which have same names as the second contract, so you have to use `override` to make it clear it is override from the function with same name in the previous contract

Comment: could you share all the code? it seems that your contract is inheriting from others

Comment: @jeissoni22 I've added all the code now, let me know what you think

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is implement an ERC20 token. Your code must conform to the standard, how is this done? with an interface (your code). What this interface does is force your code to contain certain methods to meet the standard. (You could create your token without using the interface, but implementing all the EIP-20 standard)

[EIP-20: Token Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20)

Solidity is an object-oriented programming language that supports multiple inheritances. You can inherit from a base contract and then override a function in that base contract. Before Solidity 0.6, there was no way of knowing what functions should be overridden. Now, you can explicitly label a function as virtual or override.

[Official documentation -- overriding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/contracts.html#function-overriding)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint256 balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint256 remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokens) external returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint256 tokens);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Safe Math Library
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a); c = a - b; 
        
    } 
    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { 
        c = a * b; require(a == 0 || c / a == b); 
        
    } 
    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { 
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}


contract TTKN is IERC20, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it

    uint256 public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowed;

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor() {
        name = "Test Token";
        symbol = "TTKN";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;

        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

        function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
            return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
        }

        function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256 balance) {
            return balances[tokenOwner];
        }

        function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public override view returns (uint256 remaining) {
            return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
        }

        function approve(address spender, uint256 tokens) public override returns (bool success) {
            allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
            emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
            return true;
        }

        function transfer(address to, uint256 tokens) public override returns (bool success) {
            balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
            balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
            return true;
        }

        function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokens) public override returns (bool success) {
            balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
            allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
            balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
            emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks:) So to confirm we're simply adding `override` to the existing function definitions?

Comment: Finished editing the answer. I hope and help you more